# Find a set of positions of a rectangle of fixed size, which would "cover" a curve on a plane

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a curve on a plane, and a rectangle with one side much longer than the other (let's say it is a "thick segment). I need to find a set of positions of the rectangle which would include all the points of the curve. Overlaps of the rectangle positions are allowed. Possibly I would need to optimize the problem, finding the minimal set. But a good algorithm for the complete covering would be a good start.

Here is a sketch:

[image: sketch]

This is the 2D version of [this 3D problem](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43658/cover-a-3d-surface-with-2d-rectangles-of-fixed-size-allowing-overlap).

Comment: Are the sides of the rectangle fixed beforehand?

Comment: greedy algorithm could be a start, each rectangle covers as much as possible one after another. The sub-problem should be much easier to solve.

Comment: nicoguaro no, the sides are free to be put in any position

Comment: @Yimin good idea, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp. What is the tradeoff / penalty for using larger rectangles. With the information you have given, a single giant rectangle will do the job.

Comment: @MPIchael thank you for your input! The constrain is that the rectangle size is fixed, and is much smaller than the curve, with a proportion similar to what I have shown in the sketch. So, the "one rectangle takes it all" solution is not viable.

Comment: Is the subdivision of the bounding box into smaller rectangles a possible solution?